# I get the "command 'vscode.previewHtml' not found" error message on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm learning LaTeX in this period and I'm using both Atom and VSC to write it. I've installed on Visual Studio some extension for previewing the document in PDF but everytime I try to open the preview tab the error message  "command 'vscode.previewHtml' not found" appears.
I can't understand why does it happen and how to solve it.
Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Which extension are you using for previewing the document in pdf?

Answer (score 1):

The extension may no longer work because the 'vscode.previewHtml' is deprecated. see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62630).

> The **vscode.previewHtml** command has been deprecated since the introduction of the **webview API**. The webview API is significantly easier to work with, correctly supports different filesystem setups, and webviews also offer many security benefits over htmlPreviews. **For these reasons, we would like all extensions to switch over the using the webview API and eventually remove the vscode.previewHtml command entirely**.

You have not mentioned which extension you are using, therefore what I can suggest is to update the extension and see if it solves your issue.

If you are using [VSCode Latex Preview Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajshort.latex-preview) then you should look for other extension which does the job.

I think that this extension is no longer being maintained, given that the last commit was 3 years ago and the issue you are facing is due to changes made in the month of may last year. Unless the issue if fixed by the author of the extension there is nothing that can be done by you.